# Nothing happens when I try to create a new java project on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have downloaded Eclipse classic and when I try to create a new project and finish the new java project wizard, it doesn't show anything, could someone please help?

Comment: Are you looking in the Project explorer tab ?

Answer (score 1):

Once you're done creating a project folder, create a JAVA class. That'll open the editor with a Hello World program. You can code in that file.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I have tried creating a class as well but it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check in Project explorer tab whether Working Set are shown on top. If yes, make sure the working set in which you cretaed the project is selected.

Note, working set is created automatically in project creation wizard. You need to untick the checkbox if you dont want working set.

Comment: Thank you for your response but "select working set option" is greyed out

Comment: Can you try creating a project without ticking the working set option in project create wizard ?